# During Integrating Razorpay Payment Gateway Payment is not happening?

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

This is the Error Message that is showing 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.getDeviceDetails is not a function", source: https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/public?version=1.5.16&library=checkoutjs&platform=android (1)

Help Me in this Regards

Comment: When I was passing Rs. 10 for payment then getting the same error; 
while if I pass a greater value for example Rs. 250, then it is working fine in my case.
May be there is minimum transaction limit...

Comment: sorry ..but its not working yet ..with same error

Comment: @tejraj, this is happening because the money you are providing is taken as paise by Razorpay and the minimum amount you can pay 1Rs(i.e 100).

Comment: I am having same issue. Even though I am providing 200 as amount it's not working. When I am debugging the amount and order in console of backend, the amount is printing correctly, but only at frontend after creating order the amount is undefined:/. Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Even used parseInt and Float nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this Code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _razorpay = Razorpay();
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
    _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _razorpay.clear();
  }

  void openCheckout() async {
    var options = {
      'key': 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
      'amount': 2000,
      'name': 'Acme Corp.',
      'description': 'Fine T-Shirt',
      'prefill': {'contact': '8888888888', 'email': 'test@razorpay.com'},
      'external': {
        'wallets': ['paytm']
      }
    };

    try {
      _razorpay.open(options);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    }
  }

  void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "SUCCESS: " + response.paymentId, timeInSecForIos: 4);
  }

  void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "ERROR: " + response.code.toString() + " - " + response.message,
        timeInSecForIos: 4);
  }

  void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "EXTERNAL_WALLET: " + response.walletName, timeInSecForIos: 4);
  }
```

**The above error occurs when your provided money is not in correct format. RazorPay accepts money only in paise, therefore if you provide money in decimal format(i.e double) or any value less than 100 then it will throw that error. So if you have any decimal value try converting it as integer paise. I'm attaching a small code as well for reference.**

```
 RegExp regex = RegExp(r"([.]*0)(?!.*\d)");
 double money = double.parse(widget.totalMoney);
    double tMoney = money*100;
    String stringMoney = tMoney.toString().replaceAll(regex, '');
    int totalMoney = int.parse(stringMoney);
```

The regular expression will remove zero after the decimal from stringMoney. Or directly converting it into string will also do the same.

**Hope this will help :)**

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue of mismatched Key IDs and Key secrets. Try double checking to see if the code has a consistent Key ID and Key secret. Especially in case you have switched over from a test account to a live account.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check that your API key is valid. It's due to an error in your API key or secret code.